# How to calculate HarmonicNumber(x, 1.6)?

Tags: summation, harmonic-analysis, wolfram-alpha

[I got this solution while using Wolframalpha:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=HarmonicNumber%28n,%201.6%29&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_%2aMath-)

$$
(-1.66667 n+1/2-0.133333/n+0.0208/n^3-0.0127573/n^5+O((1/n)^6))/n^1.6+2.28577
$$

Could somebody tell me this solution step-by-step?

I need to write a function to calculate this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer:
http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber2/02/0003/
describes that:

H_n^(1.6) = sum_(k=1)^n 1/k^r where r = 1.6